# Get OneNote pages through its web API

Tags: node.js, api, onenote

I'm trying to develop a NodeJS that interact with the OneNote API. Currently I;m trying to retrieve the content (the HTML) of the onenote pages.

Based on the documentation (http://dev.onenote.com/docs) that is possible using he beta API, which should be www.onenote.com/api/beta/sections/{id}/pages, but I've tried many times without success. I always get an error response:

```
403
{
  "error":{
    "code":"40004","message":"The OAuth token provided does not have the necessary scopes to complete the request. Please make sure you are including one of the following scopes: Office.onenote_update,Office.onenote_update_by_app,Office.onenote","@api.url":"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=400836"
  }
}
```

I know the API works because the Web client that is present in the API Reference [here](http://dev.onenote.com/docs) works well.

If someone could shed some light on this, I would appreciated.

Thank in advance.

P.S. I can perfectly access non-beta endpoint in the same API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving this error because you haven't requested (and subsequently had the user grant) read permissions for the user's notebook, not because it is a beta API – the permissions for `/v1.0` and `/beta` are identical.

[This article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn807159%28v=office.15%29.aspx) explains all of the scopes for the OneNote API.

The summary of that article is:

- You'll want the `office.onenote_update_by_app` if you only need to create and recall pages for your application.
- `office.onenote_update` will give you carte blanche CRUD access to all of a user's OneNote content
- `office.onenote` and `office.onenote_create` will let you access a user's pages and create new pages, but not make edits to any of the user's notebooks, sections, or pages.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly!! clearly these are my first steps with the API.