# Unable to retrieve notes with the OneNote API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, get, rest-client, onenote

Aim: Use Rails to retrieve list of notes in a defined section. As seen in lines 249-287 of [GetPagesExample.cs](https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal/blob/master/OneNoteServiceSamplesWinUniversal.Shared/OneNoteApi/Pages/GetPagesExample.cs)
Problem: Receiving 401 when I attempt a `GET`. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn575430.aspx) indicates "**401 - Unauthorized** Problems occurred in authenticating the token, user or your app".

I'm using the [OneNoteAPISampleRuby](https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleRuby) as baseline, to achieve this. The sample comes with examples of how to `POST` but no examples of how to `GET`. Posting from the sample app in my local environment works fine. I know that doing a `GET` on this request URL `https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/sections/{sectionId}/pages` works in the [OneNote API Console](https://apigee.com/onenote/embed/console/onenote). This is the URL i'm trying to get to work from my modifications to the sample app.

My modifications are as follows:
`<button type="submit" name="submit" value="quotes">Get Quotes</button>` at line 10 of [index.html.erb](https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleRuby/blob/master/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb)

```
when 'quotes'
    result = onenote_client.get_page_in_section(access_token)
```

at line 29 of [welcome_controller.rb](https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleRuby/blob/master/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb)

I added a `get_page_in_section` method to [one_note_sharer.rb](https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleRuby/blob/master/lib/one_note_sharer.rb) as seen here: https://gist.github.com/komplexb/347b7dd61ed3338ab6f4
It uses the [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem for the `POST` examples, so I've been looking at the docs for how to use `GET` but it appears I've hit a wall.

I noticed someone had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453800/get-onenote-pages-through-its-web-api/26454100#26454100), however that answer hasn't been useful for me, since scope `office.onenote` should give me read access at least according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn807159(v=office.15).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as if the issue was with how headers and params are combined for `GET` requests in rest-client library, as seen [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/README.rdoc#passing-advanced-options). Corrected [get_page_in_section](https://gist.github.com/komplexb/347b7dd61ed3338ab6f4#file-get_page_in_section-rb) method.